# How do I get the VT running X in my LXC container to my host?

Tags: xorg, lubuntu, virtualization, lxc

I'm trying to run Lubuntu within an LXC container on my host already using a GUI.

Is it possible to redirect the X output from the container to say; VT9 rather than VT7? If so where is the VT7 setting? Will this work given that I only have one graphics card?

Any help is greatly appreciated.